# .getImageData not producing intended results

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the color value off of a image that I've drawn on a canvas. Unfortunately, I'm getting a 0 from the console log, and I'm not quite sure why. I'll put some code below.

The JS here is at the beginning of my script, and the html is for the canvas. I don't want the canvas to be visible to the user, so I used the overlay feature.

```js
const position = document.getElementById("show_position");
var image = document.getElementById("imge");
const color = document.getElementById('color');
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 2160, 2160);
```

```html
<img id="imge" src="height-maps/basrahheight.png" width="2160" height="2160" alt="Height-Map" hidden>

<div id="container" onmousemove="event">
  <div id="overlay">
    <img id="map" src="images/basrah.png" alt="Map" width="2160" height="2160">
  </div>
  <canvas style="border: 0px solid black" x="0" y="0" width="2160" height="2160" id="canvas" ></canvas>
  </div>
```

This is at the end of my script, and most of my script is inside a function for the mouse movement of the container.

```js
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  var x = e.offsetX;
  var y = e.offsetY;
  var data = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
  var rgba = data.data;
  console.log(rgba);
  //this is the part I'm not sure works. The output of the console log is always 0, even if I have it output the variable "data"
});

//everything below has worked before, but maybe I've done something wrong
let r = ctx.getImageData(x, y, canvas.width, canvas.height).data[0];
let norm = 1000 - (r * 1000 / 255);
var fnorm = norm.toFixed(1);


var coords = `${sletter}${snumber}-${isnumber}-${issnumber}<br /> ${fnorm} Meters`;

  const offset = 10;
  position.style.transform = `translate(${x + offset}px, ${y + offset}px)`;

    position.innerHTML = coords;
}
```

If you have any suggestions or pointers, it would be greatly appreciated. I've tried to find some examples or posts of this before, but haven't found any.

Comment: Are you sure your image is drawn on the canvas? You are not waiting for it to load. Also, getting a single pixel through getImageData is almost always a bad choice. Get once the full data and check the pixel at x, y coords from that unique ImageData.

Comment: @Kaiido I've tried using window.onload and image.onload, but the problem is, I still don't get a result. The data is always 0. I also have no way of checking if my image is drawn on the canvas, as it is covered up by the image. 
How would I get the full data as well?

Comment: You can test by not covering the canvas. And to get the full data you do `img_data = ctx.getImageData(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height)`